# Onscroll toggle failing to add or remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to js but I am trying to get this to fire so that my nav div will stick to the top of the screen I am not sure if my window on the scroll function is firing correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $('#commons').window.onscroll(function(direction) {
    $('.main-nav').toggleClass('fixed-nav', direction == 'down');
    $('.main-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $('.main-nav a.commons-btn').addClass('active');
  }, {
    offset: '90px'
  });
});
```

Comment: Is window a property on the jquery object? Also do you want to be toggling classes and removing classes possibly hundreds of times as you scroll?

Comment: window is not a property on the jquery object. the jquery scroll event is `.on('scroll'` or `.scroll(` not `.onscroll` and the no form of `.scroll` `.on('scroll'` or the non-jquery `.onscroll` takes a parameters object as the 2nd argument

Comment: @window is not I see that i made a typo on that, I just want it to stick to the top of the window when it scrolls to next section

Comment: Have a look at CSS position sticky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function() { 
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll_pos > 210) {
             // Type here your script, this will run on scrolling
        } else {
            // This script will run when the scroll bar is on the top 
        }
    });
});
```